# UWP: How to wrap content in a FlipView?

Tags: windows, alignment, uwp, stretch, flipview

In an UWP-App I'm developing I make use of a `FlipView`.

My problem is, that I'd like the `FlipView` (more precise: its `FlipViewItems`) to wrap their content. For example: a `FlipViewItem` with a `StackPanel` as its content should have the dimensions of that said child. (like 'wrap_content' in Android)

Unlike wanted, the `FlipView` and its items keep stretching over the complete screen. I'm already adjusting things like the alignments in a custom style, but at the moment I'm only successful with changing the width/height hardcoded.

Is there a way to bind the width/height of a `FlipViewItem` to its child?
For example the behaviour of a `StackPanel` is perfect: it just adapts it size to the child's size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

I'm binding the dimensions of my `FlipView` to the `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight`-Property of the currently selected item

```
Height="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ActualHeight, ElementName=MyFlipView}"
Width="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ActualWidth, ElementName=MyFlipView}"
```